# Dockerize Phoenix Application and use a virtual host

Tags: docker, docker-compose, phoenix-framework

I'm trying to setup my environment to develop Phoenix apps using Docker.

Unitil this point everything is great, except the **VIRTUAL_HOST** part, I'd like to access my app by visiting `app.dev` instead of `localhost:4000`.

I'm using this docker-compose.yml file :

```
version: '2'

services:

  proxy:
    image: jwilder/nginx-proxy
    ports:
      - 80:80

  postgres:
    image: postgres:latest
    restart: always
    environment:
      - POSTGRES_USER=postgres
      - POSTGRES_PASSWORD=root

  web:
    build: .
    command: mix phx.server
    volumes:
      - .:/app
    ports:
      - 4000:4000
    depends_on:
      - postgres
    environment:
      - MIX_ENV=dev
      - VIRTUAL_HOST=app.dev
      - VIRTUAL_PORT=4000
      - POSTGRES_USER=postgres
      - POSTGRES_PASSWORD=root
    links:
      - postgres
```

when I try to access the app.dev I'm getting site can't be reached.

**edit #1**
For using VIRTUAL_HOST, do I really need the reverse proxy for this ? or a simple dns or something will be enough ?

**edit #2**
Ok, that's strange, when I curl the app.dev I get the html content, but I can't access it (app.dev) from the browser.

Comment: You don't need a reverse proxy, but it's nice to have in place when/if you add more services. Did you add `app.dev` to your hosts file? When using jwilder/nginx-proxy in dev.. sometimes it gets confused when containers are stopped and started quickly. `docker-compose restart proxy` solves that quickly.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need `nginx`, you just need to add `app.dev` to your `/etc/hosts` file.

```
127.0.0.1 app.dev
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer, but the result is the same. does not work at all, there is this example that uses it https://github.com/maxcnunes/elixir-phoenix-rest-api/blob/master/docker-compose.yml but I don't know what I'm messing